# $routeProvider - where is the var passed to .when stored

Tags: angularjs

I am an amateur with angular. I am using route provider to load separate html pages and controllers. This works fine when I know what pages the site has and I can define them.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/page1", {
            templateUrl: "../page1.html",
            controller: "Page1Ctrl"
        })
        .when("/page2", {
            templateUrl: "../page2.html",
            controller: "Page2Ctrl"
        })
        .when("/page3", {
            templateUrl: "../page3.html",
            controller: "Page3Ctrl"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/page1"
        });
});
```

However, in future, more pages may be added and I want to code a way for angular to take this into accout. Something like;

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {

      (..figure out n...)

     $routeProvider
         .when("/page"+n, {
               templateUrl: "../page"+n+".html",
               controller: "Page"+n+"Ctrl"
         })
         .otherwise({
               redirectTo: "/page1"
         });
});
```

I cannot figure out how to return a `var` listing the current page so I can remove '/page' to manipulate the int as `n`.

I tried console logging `$routeProvider` but `.when` simply returns a function. I don't think injecting `$scope` is wise because obviously a var is passed somewhere using `$routeProvider` alone.

Comment: I don't understand >>> _I cannot figure out how to return a var listing the current page so I can remove '/page' to manipulate the int as n_ ??

Comment: use route as /page/:num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use colon (:) in the route, Angular will parse that and populate the $routeParams with it, then, in your templateUrl, instead of a string, you can use a function which returns the template url. Just inject the $routeParams in the templateUrl's function and build the url you need.

```
$routeProvider
  .when( '/page/:pageNumber', { 
      templateUrl: function ($routeParams) {
          return 'page_' + $routeParams.pageNumber + '.html'
      }
    })
 .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/page/1' } );
```

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NEuJ6/103/).

Comment: This works for templateURL thanks, but how to also incorporate pageNumber into choosing the proper controller? controller: "Page" + pageNumber + "Ctrl" throws an undefined error

Comment: No way to do that with ngRoute, you could use the ngController directive in each template (if there is no need to resolve/inject anything), otherwise I suggest you have a look at the [ui-router's controllerProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)